# what means name="135" in button in formview odoo 10

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10, formview

i want to inherit from a method in odoo 10 so i checked in from view to know his name but i find that the  method are called using a number not his name!

some methods in odoo are called from number like the method below. i want to know what means that number and how i can find a method called by his number in form view

Code:

```
<button name="135" string="Print" states="done" type="action" groups="base.group_user"/>

<button name="143" string="Return" states="done" type="action" groups="base.group_user"/>
```

where and how i can fin a method with the name 135 ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the ***id*** of the ***action*** how is called by the button... on module view, you have something like

```
<button name="%(rest_checkout_send)d" string="Enviar" type="action"/>
```

but when you install the module you get

```
<button name="723" string="Enviar" type="action" />
```

you can check the id of the actions in Setting->Actions->Actions